ID Japanese anime movie, schoolgirl who is constantly getting bullied
I need to know the name of a movie I saw a long time ago. It was definitely before 2010. I'm not sure when it came out. It was sometime between 2000 and 2010 when I saw it on TV. I believe it was about 2004/2005.
I believe it was a Japanese anime movie. 
I remember it was about a schoolgirl who is constantly getting bullied. She goes onto this website that claims to help with bullies, she asks for help, but she doesn't get a response. 
She gets fed up and decides to kill herself. She jumps off of a building (I remember this scene the most, I don't know why: She is falling headfirst. This ghost-like person is suddenly falling right next to her, also falling headfirst). Suddenly, they aren't falling anymore; they are in this purgatory-like place. 
The ghost person is basically telling the main character that she can help with her bully by sending her to a hell-like place, but the main character would have to pay by ALSO being forced to get sent to the place. 
I think I vaguely remember the enemy/bully getting taken away on a small boat? I know the movie takes place in a Japanese school because they are all wearing kind of stereotypical Japanese schoolgirl clothes.

This is the anime series Hell Girl. The titular character is like a revenge demon (she has to do this as part of her own punishment), and the bullying victims do exactly what you say. They sacrifice their own lives and after lives so that their tormentor also gets damned. The series is mostly self contained episodes with a new victim and bully almost every episode.

Great find - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hell_Girl_episodes#Episode_list
